# ajax link json datatype call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send the data via ajax to other page. I have isolated the problem. This is the code.

Thank you all for your help..But no effect..

**updated code**

It worked...

```
<script>

     $(document).ready(function(){

     $(".edit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //<--- to prevent the default behaviour
    var box = 1233;
    var size=123;
    var itemname=123;
    var potency=123;
    var quantity=12333;

    var dataString ={
                'box' :box,
                'size':size ,
                'itemname':itemname,
                'potency':potency,
                'quantity':quantity
                };


    $.ajax({
            url: "dd.php",
            type: "post",
            data: dataString,

            success: function(data) {
            alert(data); 

            },
            error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            }
            });

       });
       });

    </script>
```

So I click the link,it navigates, to dd.php which has

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('itemcode'=>$_POST['itemname']));
   echo $_POST['itemname'];

?>
```

I get Object Object as alert. What am doing wrong? Pls throw some light here..thanks you..

Comment: which alert : one in success or the one in error ?

Comment: because your datatype is json. try doing echo json_encode($_POST['itemname']);

Comment: `dataString` is not json type while you're telling php that you're passing data in a json format.

Comment: @pXL it is the success part

Comment: You need to prevent the default action of the click if it actually navigates to dd.php? add `event.preventDefault()` right below the `$(".edit").click` line

Comment: @adeneo Thank you for your time.. but no effect :(..

Comment: @GGio it tried, but no effect :( .. Thank you anyway..

Comment: @user2234992 : since return Datatype is 'JSON' so php file should return json output only, so remove  echo $_POST['itemname']; from php file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".edit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {"box":1233,
   "size":565,
   "itemname":565,
   "potency":876,
   "quantity":234};

            $.ajax({
            url: "dd.php",
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            if(console){
    console.log(data);
}
            },
            error: function(data) {
            if(console){
    console.log(data);
}
            }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you.. I get status text:ok ..not sure if data is returning..Thank you again :) will check and let you know

Comment: Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="OK"} I am getting this in console.. Is this success ?

Comment: that is a success ;).  don't be afraid to log something in dd.php, so you can debug what to do with the data now that dd.php is receiving it.

Answer (score 1):

few things to consider... you can post data as object..which is clean and easier to use

```
$(".edit").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //<--- to prevent the default behaviour
var box = 1233;
....
var dataString ={'box':box,'size':size,'itemname':itemname,'potency':potency,'quantity':quantity};
$.ajax({
        url: "dd.php",
        type: "post",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json", //<--- here this means the response is expected as JSON from the server
        success: function(data) {
        alert(data.itemcode); //<--here alert itemcode
        },
        error: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        }
        });
```

so you need to send the response as json in PHP

```
<?php
   echo json_encode(array('itemcode'=>$_POST['itemname']))
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.. I tried this..It still alert Object object.. Could this do something with jquery versions??

Comment: I use this version <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: @user2234992 jquery version doesnot matter actually.... but i forgot to add `echo` infront of `json_encode` in PHP.. try it out.. this should work.. let me know if problem still exists

Comment: I added up the echo.. Still no effect.. Thank you for your time..I appreciate it.. I have no extra code apart from this.. Any idea..

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using querystring as sent in GET request.

If you want to send the data in same form, you can use this with GET request type:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "dd.php"+dataString,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              alert(data.itemcode);
            },
            error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            }
      });
```

Or for POST request,you will have to put data in json object form, So you can use :

```
var dataString ={
            'box' :box,
            'size':size ,
            'itemname':itemname,
            'potency':potency,
            'quantity':quantity
            };

            $.ajax({
            url: "dd.php",
            type: "post",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
                     alert(data.itemcode);
            },
            error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            }
            });
        });
```

And put echo in your php code :

```
<?php

echo json_encode(array('itemcode'=>$_POST['itemname']))

?>
```

Javascript alert shows [Object object] for object. You can see response using `console.log` or can use that key with alert.

For more information, refer [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Tried, no effect.. could there is some other issue to consider..Any idea.. Btw thanks..

Comment: @user2234992 :answer updated as per question update. please check

Comment: I got it working.. I removed the datatype:"json" and It worked..Thank you for you help..Thanks

Comment: @user2234992 : for making your code working, remove echo $_POST['itemcode'] line from php, and don't remove datatype:'json', then it'll work. For datatype:'json', php file should return json object